# Decorating a recursive function

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, scoping

Edit: I didn't do a good job explaining my question. I was confused about how with closures, the function seems to remember its previous environment, but with recursive calls it seems to find the updated value of the name.

My confusion was resolved perfectly by [Thomas Ballinger "Finding closure with closures" talk](https://youtu.be/E9wS6LdXM8Y?t=825):

> Scope of a variable is determined at definition, value of a variable is determined at execution.

So with either recursion or closures, the binding of the name was defined at definition, but the value can be still updated afterwards.

Original question:

Decorators work on recursive functions without any extra effort:

```
def debug(f):
    def new_f(*args, **kwargs):
        print('arguments:', *args, **kwargs)
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return new_f

@debug
def f(n):
    if n > 1:
        return f(n-1)*n # f refers to the decorated version!
    else:
        return 1
```

What mechanism in python ensures that `f` in the line `return f(n-1)*n` points to the decorated version of `f` rather than to the original?

I thought a function remembers its context at the time it's defined (so that with closures, the inner function can use the objects from the outer function). But when `f` was defined, the decorator hadn't been applied yet, so shouldn't `f` *inside* the function `f` refer to the undecorated version forever? Obviously, I misunderstood something in function scoping / context rules, but what?

Comment: It's more the absence of mechanism to make it point anywhere else. Remember that `@debug` is just syntactic sugar for defining the function then calling `f = debug(f)`, wherever you look for `f` you now get the decorated version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that python will look up the name `f` when the function is *executed* (and *not* when it compiles it) and see that it is the decorated version:

```
>>> f
<function __main__.debug.<locals>.new_f>
```

Since the name `f` is essentially re-binded by applying the decorator, that is the `f` that is going to be used whenever its name is looked-up.

Comment: I see. But then, what about an inner function in a closure? How does a name in it manage to link to an object based on the time of the inner function's definition, rather than its execution?

Comment: The answer to my comment is in the edit to my question.